# Filter for TIME part of TIMESTAMP doesn't work (JPA2, HIBERNATE)

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

I would like to filter by the time part of a timestamp.
I use **JPA2** with **hibernate** and **oracle** database. I have to write a JPA query, which returns entities, which "*std*" properties's TIME part is higher than the parameter's TIME part.
I'm not able to change the database side, and I cannot use native query.

For example I would like to search all entities which std time is greater than 12:01. So I put this date parameter in my JPA query: 2013-11-11T12:01:01, but nothing happens, the result list contains elements with std parameter (11:00) 2013-12-13T11:00:00.

My query looks like this:

```
Query q = em.createQuery( "SELECT t  FROM Foo t WHERE t.std >= :p_1 ");
q.setParameter("p_1", myDate, TemporalType.TIME);
```

where my date is: 2013-12-11T12:01:01
(if I use toString: Wed Dec 11 12:01:01 UTC 2013 )

In Entity class, the *std* property looks like this:

```
private java.util.Date std;

@javax.persistence.Column(name = "STD", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true)
@javax.persistence.Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
public java.util.Date getStd()
{
    return std;
}

public void setStd(java.util.Date value)
{
    this.std = value;
}
```

I also tried to change the annotation of the propertys in the entityClass to this:

```
@javax.persistence.Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.TIME)
public java.util.Date getStd()
{
    return std;
}
```

but it didn't help.

In sql, the std property is TIMESTAMP:

```
"STD" TIMESTAMP (6) NOT NULL ENABLE,
```

I must use JPA query with hibernate, the native query is not an option.
Can someone explai why it doesn't work and how can I do it properly?

Thanks!

Edit:

For example If the std values are the following in database:

```
2013-12-08T10:00:00 
2013-12-08T14:00:00 
2013-12-11T10:00:00 
2013-12-11T14:00:00 
2013-12-14T10:00:00 
2013-12-14T14:00:00
```

And I put **"2013-12-11T12:00:00"** in the query, I would like to get back all entities, which "*std*" has higher TIME, regardless from the date. In this example, these:

```
2013-12-08T14:00:00
2013-12-11T14:00:00 
2013-12-14T14:00:00
```

If I check hibernate debug log, I can see the std is mapped to org.hibernate.TimeType.

> [org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1)
>   getDataType() : std -> org.hibernate.type.TimeType@f600d7a
>
> [org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode]
>   (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Resolved : t.std -> foo0_.STD
>
> [org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode]
>   (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Resolved : t -> foo0_.ID

Comment: ... Do you have more than one day's worth of data in that table?  what do you want to happen for the next day (or any other time)?

Comment: Edited my question, and put an example in it. Regardless from the date part, I would like to get back all entities (even if the date part is in the future), which std's time part is higher than the sample date's time part. (I have to store the full date in database for other queries, but here I only want to filter by the time part of the date)

Comment: Don't forget to accept your own answer!  (when you can)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is:

```
Query q = em.createQuery( 
    "SELECT t FROM Foo t WHERE ( EXTRACT(HOUR FROM t.std) * 60 + EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM t.std) ) >= :p_1" 
    );

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(myDate);

int minutes = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) * 60 + cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
q.setParameter("p_1", minutes);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apparently use (some, at least) SQL Functions in Hibernate/HQL.  This includes `CAST`, and requires that the DB respond appropriately (ie, `TIME` type exists and is castable from `TIMESTAMP`).  **If** it works, it will probably work about like this:

```
Query q = em.createQuery( "SELECT t  FROM Foo t WHERE CAST(t.std as TIME) >= :p_1 ");
```

(please note I don't have a backing db/Hibernate instance to test this with.  May depend on version of Hibernate too.)

Note that this will ignore any indices!  This is more a function of the fact that you're only querying on part of the data, rather than some deficiency on Hibernate's part

Comment: Thanks. I tried it, but it didn't work with hibernate 4.2 and oracle11g.